# update foreign key from key in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I need a query that will take the primary key from one table (table 2) and place it in a second table (table 1) as a foreign key. The database is Microsoft Access 2007.  I tried the following query but it did not work:

```
update table1 
set table1.table2ID = table2.ID
FROM table1  INNER JOIN  table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

The two tables are as follows:

Table 1:

```
ID  | table2ID  | Name
--------------------------
1   |           |   Name1   
2   |           |   Name2   
3   |           |   Name1
```

Table 2:

```
ID    | Name
-----------------
1     |    Name1   
2     |    Name2
```

I want the result to be:

Table 1:

```
ID  | table2ID  | Name
--------------------------
1   |       1   |   Name1   
2   |       2   |   Name2   
3   |       1   |   Name1
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Did any of the two answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
SET table1.table2ID = table2.ID
```

or this:

```
update table1, table2
SET table1.table2ID = table2.ID
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
```

Let me know which one works for you best.

Answer (score -1):

U can try this :

update TABLE1 set tabel2id = TABLE2.Id from TABLE1 s
inner join TABLE2 s on  u.name = s.NAME

It worked for me..